# Relative Layout, textView not showing below button?

Tags: android-studio

I've been working on my app and i've come across an issue where in the preview, whenever i place text below the button for example the "roomservice" button it doesnt show it on the emulator when running but it does in the preview. What am i doing wrong here?

This is my xml code as its the only coding part i've been working on, i've also added `android:layout_below="@id/roomservice"/>` in the textview but it still did not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".MainMenu">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/roomservice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_room_service_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="497dp"
    android:text="Room Service"
    android:textColor="#F8F1F5F4"
    android:textFontWeight="14"
    android:layout_below="@id/roomservice"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/transportation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="237dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="237dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="238dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_taxi" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/foodservice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="239dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_restaurant" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/maintenance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="234dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_maintenance" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/checkout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="368dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_checkout" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/baggagecollection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="234dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="234dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="373dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bag" />
```

Comment: Remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from the TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the line:

`android:layout_alignParentStart="true"`

from the markup for the textview. This parameter, according to the documentation, will "make the start edge of this view match the start edge of the parent". Both the `TextView` and The first `ImageButton` have the same parent (the layout), so your views could be generating on top of each other.

The 'start' position is also dependent on on the locale setting of the device. This might explain why the layout is displaying differently across devices.